# Convert string column to json and parse in pyspark

Tags: json, dictionary, pyspark, azure-databricks

My dataframe looks like

```
|ID|Notes|
---------------
|1|'{"Country":"USA","Count":"1000"}'|
|2|{"Country":"USA","Count":"1000"}|

ID : int
Notes : string
```

When i use from_json to parse the column Notes, it gives all Null values.
I need help in parsing this column Notes into columns in pyspark

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do you get the column Notes?

Comment: show your code that you use to parse

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `from_json()` function, make sure that the column value is exactly a json/dictionary in String format. In the sample data you have given, the `Notes` column value with `id=1` is not exactly in json format (it is a string but enclosed within additional single quotes). **This is the reason it is returning NULL values.** Implementing the following code on the input dataframe gives the following output.

```
df = df.withColumn("Notes",from_json(df.Notes,MapType(StringType(),StringType())))
```

[image]

You need to change your input data such that the entire Notes column is in same format which is json/dictionary as a string and nothing more because it is the main reason for the issue. The below is the correct format that helps you to fix your issue.

```
| ID | Notes |
---------------
| 1 | {"Country":"USA","Count":"1000"} |
| 2 | {"Country":"USA","Count":"1000"} |
```

To parse Notes column values as columns in pyspark, you can simply use function called `json_tuple()` (no need to use from_json()). It extracts the elements from a json column (string format) and creates the result as new columns.

```
df = df.select(col("id"),json_tuple(col("Notes"),"Country","Count")) \
    .toDF("id","Country","Count")
df.show()
```

Output:

[image]

**NOTE:** json_tuple() also returns null if the column value is not in the correct format (make sure the column values are json/dictionary as a string without additional quotes).